# How to create and save a file in vc++

Tags: visual-c++

I have a file which is open and read the content of the file in vc++. Then it is encrypted. I need to save this encrypted data to another newly created file. How can I save this encrypted data to the newly created file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - opens and creates files.
 
[WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) - writes into file.

If you use MFC, check [this stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey6xh9bk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).